# Incrementing image src based on scroll position with jQuery

Tags: jquery, for-loop, scroll, src

I would like to use jQuery to have the background-image attribute of a div increase by 1 every time the user scrolls a certain amount, like 30 pixels. I have about 40 images named frame1.jpg, frame2.jpg, etc. I successful achieved this effect by setting a condition for each step (show frame1 after 30 pixels, frame 2 after 60 pixels, etc.), but when I try to do it with a "for" loop, as soon as I scroll, it goes to frame3.jpg, the image before the last, and after the next 30 pixels it jumps to the last image (frame4.jpg).

I will actually use this in a horizontal parallax-style layout but I wanted to understand the technique in the simplest possible way first.

Here is what I tried (with only 4 frames), and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  position:absolute;
}

#inner { 
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#inner").css("background-image", "url(http://holis.ro/frames/frame1.jpg");

$(window).scroll(function() {
   var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if (value < 40 * i)
      $("#inner").css("background-image", "url(http://holis.ro/frames/frame" + i +".jpg)");
      else if (value < 40 * (i+1))
      $("#inner").css("background-image", "url(http://holis.ro/frames/frame" + (i+1) +".jpg)"); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a rolation between `scrollTop()` value.

And user this :

```
var oldindex = 1;    
$(window).scroll(function() {

    //floor or ceil to get int valeu
    var newindex = Math.Math.ceil($(this).scrollTop()/ 30 ) //30 px

    if(newindex!=oldindex && newindex<=40){ //add limitation 40 images
        $("#inner").css("background-image", "url(http://holis.ro/frames/frame"+newindex+".jpg");
        oldindex = newindex
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! But I had to remove the first Math. from the respective line, so I used:

    `var newindex = Math.ceil($(this).scrollTop() / 30 ) //30 px`

If I didn't remove it I got the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ceil' of undefined".

I'm not sure if the line

    `oldindex = newindex`

is needed, the code works even if I remove it.

Comment: You are welcome @DanM, glad that it works. Ok, Customize it to your taste.